Motion Tracking: cannot set Floor
I want to motion track a video but I have the following problem: whenever I define the floor with three trackers, the camera seems to move miles away from the tracking scene. It seems that Blender does not recognize my floor as such. The solve error is 0.05, so this shouldn't be the problem. I first tried to motion track a clip that I stabilized by using After Effects' Warp Stabalizer. I thought this might be the reason since the effect distorts the image a little bit. But then I tried it with the original footage without Warp Stabalizer and the same problem occured. Both clips are here as png sequences:
OriginalFootage: https://we.tl/t-Dqfx52wJW4
StabalizedFootage: https://we.tl/t-RVpl0WrarH


This is not an answer to your original Question but it might still help you. First of all, your points are not on a plane. one point is on the wall, one on the floor and one on the floor but elevated. This would anyway not give you an accurate floor plane. Yo u don't have to create a floor plane to use the track. creating the floor plane never works for me and i always just do it manually by enabling the tracking points in the Viewport, selecting the trackers in the tracking preview and then manually position and rotate the plane  to intersect with those points.
